# How to access the internal ringtone folder on rooted 2.2?

Tags: internal-storage, ringtone

I have a rooted Samsung GT5510 running 2.2.
I have tried in vain, using different file explorers, to locate the built in ringtones (folder).
Can someone please point me to the right path? Is it inside some APK, in which case how do I unzip it to access the internal contents after saving it on my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `/system/media/audio/ringtones`. The notifications folder one level up contains the notification tones.